# How do I use Vuex State data in methods

Tags: vue.js, vuex, svg.js

With the following code

```
<template>
  <div :id="svgId" class="svg-container"></div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Space',

  data: function() {
    return {
      svgId: 'space',
      svgContainer: null
    }
  },

  computed: mapState({
    notes: state => state.notes
  }),

  mounted: function() {
    this.generateSpace()
  },
  methods: {
    generateSpace: function() {
      this.$svg('space')
        .rect(100, 100)
        .attr({ fill: '#f06' })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I currently just draw a pink square but what I want to do is use data from the store in the method generate space but I am unsure how to access that so for example something like this;

```
 this.$svg('space')
        .rect(notes.height, notes.width)
        .attr({ fill: notes.color })
    }
```

Any tips appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the `this` to `notes` should be enough I think.

```
 this.$svg('space')
        .rect(this.notes.height, this.notes.width)
        .attr({ fill: this.notes.color })
    }
```

Comment: ah ha yes ofcourse! my issue now is on first load data is not ready ? it is undefined once page is loaded if I edit works like a charm ? So when should I call my function as mounted is too early ?

Comment: Glad it helped :) Normally the mounted hook is triggered only when everything in the component is set up. Have you tried to put a setTimeout of some ms to check if the problem is really about the time mounted is called? Because maybe the problem is data is just not set.

Comment: erm nope, will have a play